# Installing in Program Files vs. Appdata

Tags: windows, installation

What are the benefits and downsides of installing an application in the user's AppData directory?

I assume that installing in AppData will let users in restricted environments be able to install and use the application.

Comment: Installing to AppData requires either never being successful at what you do or having a really good lawyer.

Comment: @hans-passant: what's the pun here? :)

Comment: @EuriPinhollow no real pun. It's just like Hans said - it's a crude workaround to e.g. allow restricted users to install stuff without the usual permissions. AppData was intended to be used for, obviously, app data/settings etc., not whole applications. The downsides can be severe (e.g. in network env having a roaming profile with a size measured in GBs... ugh). Thus the "or", either you're doing it for wrong reasons (and you just don't care about the implications, problems and downsides), or for very good reasons (and thus can deal with the fallout later on).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One of the benefits of installing to Program Files is that is exactly where the user expects it to go. Usually users go here first to look where the program is installed. The biggest downside is that the user needs administrative privileges, which isn't always required by the program.

You are correct in assuming installing to AppData will let restricted users install and use the application. It also will follow the user around on network systems, allowing them to have access to the program from any machine they log into with the same account. This is also a downside however since it means 2 or 3 users on a machine will have 2 or 3 versions of it installed.

Google installs its products to AppData, which is great since it can then be installed by any user (including at schools where the computers are stuck with IE6 or something).

You should use AppData for any configuration, or program files that will change with the program. I personally prefer installing programs to Program Files, because that's where users assume it will be installed, and it requires admin permissions, which is usually set for a reason, and abiding by those permissions is just nice for an app to do. Ultimately it's up to you, but the default should probably just be Program Files.

Comment: Is there any way to move AppData to a different drive? I got a C drive that's a small SSD. Also if AppData has all these advantages and Program files has the only advantage of inertia, shouldn't we try to move all apps to AppData? And AppData is such a strange place, I wish it was more obvious where it is.

Comment: I'd advise against installing to AppData unless you have really good reason to do so. Program Files is where the user will expect it, and the permissions are set up like that as well. AppData has a few flaws, namely that the program is only installed for that one user, and could actually be repeatedly installed because of that. The other thing is AppData roaming follows users on a server network, and so making that take more space could make logging in slower.

Comment: As for how to move AppData, first copy it over, then use mklink to create a folder from it's original location to the new location. You'll have to delete the folder from the C drive before you create the link, so make sure it's copied over successfully first

Comment: For reference, apps that install to `AppData` by default include Discord, Flux, GitHub Desktop, and Google Chrome.

Comment: You can add these to the list of apps that install to AppData by default: Fiddler, Freeter, and Slack. Making matters worse, sometimes these apps (eg. Freeter, and Slack in earlier versions) create desktop shortcuts to the app that actually run an updater program, then run the main app from a version-specific subfolder. This makes it difficult to maintain usable a shortcut anywhere else besides the desktop.

Comment: "It also will follow the user around on network systems, allowing them to have access to the program from any machine they log into with the same account." <-- That is not a default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Generally appears that the "Appdata" directory equates to the user software directory someone might notice using Linux systems; hadn't paid too much attention to the shift from Program Files directory installations toward the increasingly popular Appdata folder, but it slowly dawns on me.

Thread is a bit old, but relevant considering that Windows is still pretty active; Program Files installations are mostly for your touchy apps --the ones that you will want a bit more access control over like maintenance and security apps. Your Appdata folder is pretty much any other "user" specific soft like media players, text editors; etc. The "administrator" of a Windows installation will also benefit from using appdata for "normal" software along the same lines as not installing software in the root directory while administering a Linux, Mac or BSD system.