# Python no longer launches from command prompt after windows update

Tags: python, windows-10

My Windows 10 computer just installed updates and now when I go to the command prompt and type "python" the Windows store opens with a download option.

My path already includes two versions of Python for some reason:

```
C:\Users\Josh\AppData\roaming\Python\Python37\
C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
```

Any suggestions? I can type in a python script (`think.py`) and it runs as expected, but `python think.py` does nothing.

Comment: try `py` maybe?

Comment: That works, but why the change?

Comment: did you have python 2 installed before?

Comment: I think it was installed on this computer by default. I do have Python 3.6 on here but I've excised it from the windows path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python` should work in cmd if `Python` is correctly installed and added to Windows path. `py` also exists and allows for a specification of a version i.e. `py -2` or `py -3`. In your case it appears that python is installed in `appdata` and not `program files`, and this is most likely the issue with the `python` command not working! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427245/installing-in-program-files-vs-appdata) is a pretty comprehensive article on the differences between the two!

Comment: Very strange. This is my personal laptop. I don't know why Python installed under ``appdata`` twice. Should I reinstall while running the installer as an admin to get Python under Program Files?

Comment: Yeah I would rerun the installer and not let it use the default directory. Don't forget to tick the box that adds python to the system path!